# Predicate Subquery to display entity with at least 1 common object in relationship

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, data-modeling, predicate, nsfetchrequest

In a section of my data model I'm using -

```
Department <-->> Person <<-->> Project
```

I want to list all person's of departmentA that have at least 1 project in common with persons in departmentB. For example, of the list of projects personA has there needs to be at least 1 person from departmentB who also has the project. If a personB also has that project then personA is on the list. I've been struggling for a while with subquery and the direction I'm going is below. It fails with 'to-many key not allowed' other attempt have given me 'parse issue'.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projectToPerson.personToDepartment = %@", departmentB];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *projects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest2 setEntity:entity2];
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"personToDepartment = %@ AND SUBQUERY(personToProject, $x, $x.projectName = %@).@count >0", departmentA,projects];

    [fetchRequest2 setPredicate:predicate2];
```

I'm attempting to get an array of all projects and then list all persons of departmentA with a project that matches. Is this possible, and is this the right direction?

Comment: Do you already have this list of `Entity3` instances which are potential matches for your criteria? Or you're hoping to do all of that in a single predicate?

Comment: In the database I have the list of Entity3's that pair with associated Entity2's. I'll update my question to clarify.